# List of GLSL ES built-in variables

Tags: shaders, glsl, webgl, three.js

I am writing an article on WebGL and three.js, I'm trying to search all the built-in variables available in the vertex and fragment shader.

I've found many sites mentioning some, for example:

**Vertex Shader**

- modelMatrix
- modelViewMatrix
- projectionMatrix
- viewMatrix
- normalMatrix
- cameraPosition
- position
- normal
- uv
- uv2
- color
- gl_Position

**Fragment Shader**

- viewMatrix
- cameraPosition
- gl_FragColor

But I know there are more, I just can't find a resource that mentions all the built-in variables. Also, some of these variables are passed by three.js classes, I need to distinguish the built-in variables from the ones which are created by the `ShaderMaterial` class. Does someone have a list?

Comment: Only gl_Position and gl_FragColor are from GLES, the other ones are all supplied by the application itself.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the actual specification documents - http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/ - *much* better than searching random websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to look at the official quick reference card for the version of OpenGL you're working with.  It has a page for the shader language and shows all the variables.

I googled "opengl reference card" and found PDFs of all of them on the Khronos website.  For example the one I use is for OpenGL ES 2.0 and is at:

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf

The 1.0 WebGL PDF is at:

http://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf

Also, I think you might be confusing Uniforms, Attributes, and Varyings with variables.  The only built in OpenGL / WebGL variables would start with gl_.  All the other ones in your list are probably part of an implementation library (three.js?).